# How to update Windows 7 to 10 without affecting GRUB and Ubuntu installation?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, updates, windows-7

I have 2 systems on my computer: Ubuntu and Windows 7. GRUB was configured automatically during Ubuntu installation.
Microsoft now offers free update to Windows 10.
I'd like to do it but is it possible to do it without affecting GRUB?

I heard about new Windows 10 feauture called secure boot. If it will break my GRUB, what would be the proper way to acces my Ubuntu installation?

**So what's the recommended way to update Windows 7 to 10 and keep my dual boot configuration as it is?**

Comment: Secure boot is only in UEFI installs with UEFI hardware. Most Windows 7 systems were BIOS installs. Only a few later in production were on UEFI hardware and most of those were still BIOS. With BIOS installs and only one drive with one MBR, you will have to restore grub to MBR. And in Windows make sure the new fast start up or always on hibernation is off. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader Instructions are actually for all BIOS based systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get GRUB working again, you could start a Ubuntu Live System (via a LiveUSB, DVD, etc) and run `sudo update-grub` to re-install the GRUB bootloader.